# jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temperature' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть javascript код, который выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
 var period = 1;
var currentTemperature = <?php echo $currentThemperature; ?>;
var maximum = <?php echo $info['maximum'] ?>;
var minimum = <?php echo $info['minimum'] ?>;
var average = <?php echo $info['average'] ?>;
function checkPeriod(){
    period = document.getElementById('period').value;

}

var json = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        global: false,
        url: '/test/<?php echo $info['hub_id'] ?>/<?php echo $info['position'] ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {period: period},
        success: function (data) {

            json = data;
            currentTemperature = data[data.length-1].temperature;

        }
    });
```

Что означает эта ошибка?

Comment: ошибка означает, что ты пытаешься получить значение свойства `temperature` у объекта, который `undefined`.

Comment: проще всего проверить что у тебя лежит в `data`

Comment: возможно вы ничего не получаете от сервера

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, не, что-то определенно приходит, иначе ошибка была бы при попытке получить `data.length`

Comment: @Grundy приходит пустой массив

Comment: тогда очевидно, что при попытке взять у него минус первый элемент получается `undefined`, и последующее за этим исключение.

Comment: Непонятно, в чем сейчас заключается вопрос: как проверить, что массив пустой, или почему он вернулся пустой? Кроме этого не плохо было бы убедиться, что это действительно массив, а не объект